# Can I insert inline IR in an LLVM module using the C++ API?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm working on a toy language, and I want to have blocks of inline LLVM IR like this:

```
# local scope
let x = 0;
let y = 1;
inline_llvm("
%z = add i64 x i64 y
");
```

I've looked through the LLVM documentation and only found the functions in the `IRReader/IRReader.h` file, which output Modules instead of adding them to the end of a basic block. Is there a way to do this other than manually parsing the IR?

Comment: It's possible to access the regular parser, but not simple. I don't know how, but I remember noticing some useful function. Sorry, I've a flu today and my memory's fuzzy. Set a breakpoint in LLVM's lexer, run llc, look at the stacktrace. But I fear that won't help anyway, since it seems you'll need identifiers from your language, which will be complicated. IR usually has multiple values for each source variable/identifier/…